# Visual Studio 2019 remote python debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have an application running remotely on a Raspberry PI.  I can attach to it, I can Break All and it will stop and let me single step, but I can't set a breakpoint.  ptvsd.break_into_debugger() also works.

If I try to set try to set a breakpoint, the IDE shows a round white circle with a red outline next to the line and hovering over it displays:
"The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  Breakpoint in file that does not exist."